# How to cache rxdart streams in flutter for infinite scroll

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

```
class PollScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bloc.paginatePolls(null, null);

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.polls,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PollModel>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.length < 1) {
            return Text('loading...');
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              final PollModel curItem = snapshot.data[index];

              return Card(
                   //Render Logic
                );
            },
          );
        });
  }
}

class Bloc {
  final Repository _repository = Repository();
  final PublishSubject<List<PollModel>> _polls = PublishSubject<List<PollModel>>();

  Observable<List<PollModel>> get polls => _polls.stream;

  paginatePolls(int count, String last) async {
    final List<PollModel> polls = await _repository.paginatePolls(count, last);

    _polls.sink.add(polls);
  }

  dispose(){
    _polls.close();
  }
}
final bloc = Bloc();
```

I am from `react native` background in terms of mobile dev and I have used tools like `apollo` and `redux` so `rxdart` is a little bit confusing for me. `paginatePolls` just retrieves simple list of objects from the server and adds to the stream and `PollScreen` class is rendering the result. Everything works fine but I am curious how I can cache the first `paginatePolls` requests so that I can make subsequent queries with `count` (number of docs to return) `last` (id of the last item returned from previous result) and simply append the result to what is already there.

In `apollo` and `redux` I would just be adding more and more docs to the cache as I make more requests but since `rxdart` is a stream, I am unsure of which approach is the most effective.

I have thought of cacheing with sqlite but seems like a huge over kill + unsure if it would be fast enough.

Next method I have thought of is just to create a list in the bloc and keep adding items to it as more requests are made. Then stream the whole list every time. But this would mean re-creating the entire list for every stream e.g. first request render 1-50, second render 1-100, third render 1-150 where what would be preferable is - first render 1-50, second render 51-100 and just attach below the first render, etc.

How do you implement counterparts of `apollo` and `redux` cache in flutter using `rxdart`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been stuck on this similar problem. I was thinking of keeping a Map in my repository (class where you make your network requests) and just do a look up in the map from there. But I am having issues with this, since I use the "compute" method, and whatever you pass into the "compute" function cannot be a instance method. (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing)

I looked online and a few people advise against a `global bloc`, I am from a React Native + Redux background as well, but I really want to use the bloc pattern the right way, wish there were better examples out there.

Comment: I agree that there should be better examples. Right now I have gone with creating cache in the repository as I did not have any other choice. After a few thousand lines of code, single bloc does seem to get overloaded but I just do not like the idea of multiple source of states. Flutter is still new so I'll keep my heads up on where community move towards.

Comment: There are some helpful reddit threads and comments out there that may help and aid you in your solution like these ones:
- https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/96ytwv/how_do_you_handle_multiple_blocs_in_a_single/e44eh15/?context=3
- https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/a5kjlt/is_there_anything_wrong_with_defining_your_bloc/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/afucot/what_is_the_best_solution_for_managing_global/